# Unmounting usb drive corrupted my usb partition tables

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, drive, fdisk

Apparently the partition tables have larger sizes than my actual USB drive. I unmounted the drive through nautilus and now my drive won't load. How do I fix this?

here is my `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 57.7 GiB, 61941481472 bytes, 120979456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6e697373

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1       1936269394 3772285809 1836016416 875.5G 4f QNX4.x 3rd part
/dev/sdd2       1917848077 2462285169  544437093 259.6G 73 unknown
/dev/sdd3       1818575915 2362751050  544175136 259.5G 2b unknown
/dev/sdd4       2844524554 2844579527      54974  26.9M 61 SpeedStor
```

Comment: Try to install (`sudo apt install testdisk`) and run [`testdisk`](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step).

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid MBR or GPT partition table. It's possible that the disk was used *without* a partition table (just a raw filesystem covering the whole disk), or maybe it used something more exotic, like APM or BSD. Without knowing what filesystem the disk used or how (or if) it was originally partitioned, it's hard to give more specific advice. Also, you say it's a "USB drive." Is this an external hard disk, a USB flash drive, or something else?